# .NET GetProperty on .Resx Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, resources

Based on http://www.thinkingguy.net/2010/01/localizing-labelfor-in-aspnet-mvc-2.html

I'm trying to use reflection to get to a string property in a resx file

```
   var propertyInfo = _resourceType.GetProperty(resourcePropertyName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

I have a resources folder in my MVC2 project with a resource file that autogenerated a Property

```
 public static string Dagrapport_Datum {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Dagrapport_Datum", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
```

Whatever I pass to GetProperty It just stays null.... 
Any clues as to why this could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your BindingFlags doesn't match with the signature of the property.

You need BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public and maybe BindingFlags.GetProperty.

Edit: Its better to set BindingFlags.NonPublic too.

So GetProperty() searches for all Static, Public or NonPublic (internal, private, protected) properties.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply. That absolutely did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have your Acces Modifier set to "Internal"

```
var resource = typeof(TestResource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var property = resource.First(x => x.Name == "SomeProperty");
```

If you set the Acces Modifier to "Public" you can change `NonPublic` to `Public` instead.

This also works:

```
var someProperty = typeof (TestResource).GetProperty("SomeProperty", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

In this example I've got a Resource called `TestResource` with a property `SomeProperty`.